# Align column of floats at decimal point Java

Tags: java, floating-point, alignment, double

I want to align a column of floats at the decimal point. I know it is easy to do if you limit the points after decimal but i want the user to be able to enter unlimited number and length floats.

Here is the part of my program dealing with the float alignment:

```
String[] input = new String[3];
    System.out.format("%n%n\tEnter three floating point numbers%n");
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        input[i] = in.nextLine();

    System.out.format("\tHere they are lined up on their decimal point%n");

/*This is used to find decimal location in each string*/
    int[] decLoc = new int[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=input[i].length();j++)
            if(input[i].charAt(j-1) == '.') 
                decLoc[i] = j;
    }
/*print 5 spaces before number if the decimal is at place 0, 4 spaces for 1...*/ 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(decLoc[i]==0) System.out.print("      ");
        else if(decLoc[i]==1) System.out.print("     ");
        else if(decLoc[i]==2) System.out.print("    ");
        else if(decLoc[i]==3) System.out.print("   ");
        else if(decLoc[i]==4) System.out.print("  ");
        else if(decLoc[i]==5) System.out.print(" ");

        System.out.println(input[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
        Enter three floating point numbers
3265.3265
23.365
254.3256
        Here they are lined up on their decimal point
 3265.3265
   23.365
  254.3256
```

Need a better solution to align floats of varying length.

Comment: use tabs. and the decimalformatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it flexible, you can add only few lines of code to what you already have.
First, let's find out what is the longest count of digits before the dot:

```
int LENGTH = 3;
int longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint = 0;

for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++) {
    int indexOfDot = input[i].indexOf(".");

    if (longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint < indexOfDot) {
        longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint = indexOfDot;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of using your "if" conditions, add this line, which will utilise the locations of decimal points you have found earlier, and basically does what you were doing, but with added flexibility:

```
for (int j=0; j<longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint - decLoc[i] + 1; j++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Full code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int LENGTH = 3;
String[] input = new String[LENGTH];
System.out.format("%n%n\tEnter three floating point numbers%n");
for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
    input[i] = in.nextLine();

//finds the longest number of digits before the dot
int longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint = 0;

for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++) {
    int indexOfDot = input[i].indexOf(".");

    if (longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint < indexOfDot) {
        longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint = indexOfDot;
    }
}

System.out.format("\tHere they are lined up on their decimal point%n");

/*This is used to find decimal location in each string*/
int[] decLoc = new int[LENGTH];
for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
{
    //as R.J noted below, finding dot place can be done like this
    decLoc[i] = input[i].indexOf('.');
}

/*print 5 spaces before number if the decimal is at place 0, 4 spaces for 1...*/ 
for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
{
    //add spaces
    for (int j=0; j<longestCountBeforeDecimalPoint - decLoc[i] + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(input[i]);
}
```

In the output, you will have all the numbers aligned at the dot place, as requested.

Tested with randomly generated 10000 numbers, all were aligning at the dot place.

LENGTH specifies how many numbers user will enter. Of course, this can be made more flexible as well, such as terminating entering numbers when some special character is entered etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write code that calculates the biggest number of digits before the dot, an example with doubles:

```
double[] theNumbers = new double[5];
double[0] = 1324.5314564;
double[1] = 24.4;
double[2] = 0.2574;
double[3] = -56.77;
double[4] = -2.0;

int maxDigitsBeforeDot = 0;
int actExponent = 0;
boolean found = false;

while(!found) {
    found = true;
    for(double act : theNumbers) {
        if(Math.abs(act) >= Math.pow(10,actExponent)) { found = false; }
    }
    actualExponent++;
}

maxDigitsBeforeDot = actExponent;
```

With `maxDigitsBeforeDot` you have the number of digits before the dot, so you can easily create an Output format with unlimited digits after the dot, and the correct number of digits before it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of the decimal point in each String, you can use the `indexOf()` of method for that. This way you could populate the `decLoc` array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    decLoc[i] = input[i].indexOf('.');
}
```

To print, instead of having a `if` do this, you can have a method, which prints the no. of spaces based on the parameter passed, and you can call this method inside the `for` where you print the data.

```
void printSpaces(int n) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%" + n + "s", ""));
}
```

Comment: Ah! Brilliant. And can use indexOf for another problem I have! Thanks R.J

Comment: @WilfEngel - Glad that this helped you, because it was rather a surprise that you had a look at this answer, after 2 days! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic approach:

```
public class FloatFormatter {
    String[] values;
    String format;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = new String[] {
                "3265.3265999999",
                "8823999.365",
                "254.3256",
                "123"};

        FloatFormatter f = new FloatFormatter(input);
        f.printFormattedValues();
    }

    public FloatFormatter(String[] values) {
        setValues(values);
    }

    public void setValues(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
        updateFormat();
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void printFormattedValues() {
        System.out.printf("Float format: %s\n\n", getFormat());
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(String.format("Value %%d: %s\n", getFormat()),
                    i, Double.parseDouble(values[i]));
        }
    }

    protected void updateFormat() {
        byte[] lenAndFigs = getLengthAndSigFigs();
        format = String.format("%%%d.%df", lenAndFigs[0], lenAndFigs[1]);
    }

    private final byte[] getLengthAndSigFigs() {
        byte length = 0, sigFigs = 0;
        String[] parts;

        for (String value : values) {
            parts = value.split("\\.");
            length = (byte) Math.max(length, parts[0].length());

            if (parts.length > 1)
                sigFigs = (byte) Math.max(sigFigs, parts[1].length());
        }

        return new byte[] { (byte) (length + sigFigs + 1), sigFigs };
    }
}
```

Output:

Float format: %18.10f

```
Value 0:    3265.3265999999
Value 1: 8823999.3650000000
Value 2:     254.3256000000
Value 3:     123.0000000000
```